# Can DataDog dd-trace-js send trace info to the server via http headers?

Tags: reactjs, trace, datadog

I want to trace a request path that has started in the Web application React JS (frontend), then passed to the backend and returned as a response.

Can [dd-trace-js](http://%20https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-js/) start the span and pass it to the server over HTTP HEADERS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracing for requests coming from the browser are handled by RUM and not APM. I can't find the documentation for it but there is a configuration option on the [browser SDK](https://github.com/DataDog/browser-sdk/blob/701a0f81b303fad50d9f16e724af8143ab0fffe7/packages/core/src/domain/configuration.ts#L7) to allow tracing to specific endpoints. The tracing context will automatically be propagated to APM if enabled on the server side, and both the browser and server spans will appear in the same trace.